# Can we develop kde applications using a machine that runs gnome?

Tags: open-source, gnome, kde-plasma

Although I am still new at Linux and the destop environemnts, I want to know if I can develop KDE based applications from a system using GNOME as its desktop environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You just have to make sure you have the KDE libraries and development headers installed. (Should be a package named something like `kdelibs-devel` in your package manager.) You may find it difficult to test your application properly, though, for obvious reasons.